# Need help with horizontal menu with icon centered above each link

Tags: css

So far I have something like

http://jsfiddle.net/7KxTQ/

but the problem is I can't figure out how to center the icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `#mainnav ul li a:link:before, #mainnav ul li a:visited:before`, add:

```
margin: 0 auto
```

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/7KxTQ/3/)

Comment: thanks, I thought I tried that, and it didn't seem to work. Also I thought `margin: 0` auto only works if the parent have a fixed width?

Comment: The parent in this case is of course the `li` tag. The width of the `li` tag is coming from the width of the text. `margin: 0 auto` does not require an explicitly specified width - the most obvious proof for this is the eternal `<div id="container" style="margin: 0 auto">`, which will remain centered regardless of the window width. It's the same idea here.